# Import Labeled Data from vott to Google Cloud AutoML

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-automl, labeling

I want to go ahead and create a classifier, I and I do not like the Google's Browser Labeling Service. Is there a tool similar to vott or some code, that I can use to go ahead and import my vott labeled data and import it Google AutoML.

The Google Labeling Service looks something like this and is **very slow** in **loading images** and inefficient it literally has a white labeling cursor and I have light background in my images

As seen in the Image Here.
[image: Google Label]

On the Other Hand can I import it using **vott** which is much more better in every way. So is there a way for me to do this using vott to import the labeled csv into Google's Cloud AutoML.

[image: Vott]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that it is currently possible to import already labeled data from other apps (like VOTT).

At the moment there are 3 ways to label images in Cloud Vision. It's described in the [Annotating imported training images](https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/object-detection/docs/label)

- **Provide bounding boxes with labels for your training images via labeled bounding boxes in your .csv import file**

In the `CSV` file you would need to provide GCS url and label/labels

> Labeled: gs://my-storage-bucket-vcm/flowers/images/img100.jpg,daisy
>
> Multi-label: gs://my-storage-bucket-vcm/flowers/images/img384.jpg,dandelion,tulip,rose
>
> Assigned to a set: TEST,gs://my-storage-bucket-vcm/flowers/images/img805.jpg,daisy

More details can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/prepare).

- **Provide unannotated images in your .csv import file and use the UI to provide image annotations**

> Not labeled: gs://my-storage-bucket-vcm/flowers/images/img403.jpg

However, later you will need to label it using UI, otherwise it will be ignored.

> AutoML Vision ignores items without a category label.

- **Request manual image annotation with [Google's Human Labeling service](https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/object-detection/docs/label#human-labeling)**

This option would include human labelers and would need to provide additional information like dataset, label set and instructions for people.

In the documentation you can also find information that currently API is not supporting any method for labeling.

> The AutoML API does not currently include methods for labeling.

However, you can propose `Feature Request` via [IssueTracker](https://issuetracker.google.com) to add some additional import methods from different apps or enable the use API.

Comment: Thank You! There is a way to import from `label-studio` using Google Cloud Buckets. But that does not integrate with Google's AutoML.